# R markdown code chunks run with "run current chunk" but not when I knit

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to a read data file within my Rmd file.

It works fine when I use the green arrow to "run current chunk" and when I run selected lines. It does not run when I knit.

I tried chunk option  `include=TRUE` and others that I could think of. Did not work.

I started a new Rmd file using the `prettydocs template`, and I put the code into an existing chunk in that template that was running and producing output. That code chunk is below. The last two lines are what I added, and they run fine when I select and run or when I run current chunk. When I knit, everything else in the chunk runs, but not those two lines.

The other change I made to the template file was to add: `library(tidyverse)` and `library(readxl)`.

Here's the **code**:

````
```{r fig.width=6, fig.height=6, fig.align='center'}

set.seed(123)
n <- 1000    
x1 <- matrix(rnorm(n), ncol = 2)    
x2 <- matrix(rnorm(n, mean = 3, sd = 1.5), ncol = 2)    
x <- rbind(x1, x2)    
head(x)

smoothScatter(x, xlab = "x1", ylab = "x2")    

test <- read_excel("test_data.xlsx")

getwd()    
```
````

Comment: Does `set.seed(123)` is on the same line with ``` ? It can be that. Otherwise is your test_data.xlsx in the same directory with your Rmd file?

Comment: set.seed(123) is not on the first line, #```{r etc.}

Comment: can you add the error message?

Comment: set.seed(123) is not on the first line, #```{r etc.} and test_data.xlsx is in the same directory with the Rmd file. After my original post, I did more research and found some other people having problems with read_excel in R Markdown. So I tried some other packages to read excel files, unsuccessfully. Finally, created csv file as well and used read.csv. Same problem across all these situations -- code runs in chunk just fine, code does not run when I knit

Comment: When I have this I then try with xlsx file full path for instance /Users/home/.../test_data.xlsx to determine if it's that. In RStudio inside Rproj (or without) default working directory is not set the same. The `here` package helps for this. and maybe add eval = TRUE in your chunk param { } just to be sure.

Comment: There's no error message. Not in the html output, not in the console, not in the render tab.

Comment: OK, thanks. I had tried full path names before, but I'll try that again and check out the here package.

Comment: Added in the full path names, and that did not help. Tried setting up a new project and wrote a simple script to read in my test files as both csv and excel. That worked. When I say it worked, I mean the data frames a created with the imports appear in my Global Environment and I when I type the name of the dataframe into the counsel, it sees it. Next, created new Rmd file and copied the script into the Rmd as a code chunk. Knitted the Rmd file and global environment still empty.

Comment: Rmd knitting means Rmd compiles in another environment than global, it's seems normal to me not to have test df created in your RStudio environment..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240895/discussion-between-focusperson-and-guillaume).

Comment: Does it run if you comment out  `test <- read_excel("test_data.xlsx")`? What is then the result of `getwd()`?

Comment: I suggest that you restart RStudio or your R session within R Studio. Additionally, clear the knitr cache. When an RMD build doesn't complete, sometimes it leaves a window open with nothing in it. Additionally, the cache can cause some really odd behavior, as well.